# Some confusion in linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of polynomials in $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$.

Which of the following maps $T: V \rightarrow V$ are linear transformations?

$a)$ $T(p(X))=p(X^2)$ for all $p(X) \in V$.

$b)$ $T(p(X))=p(X)^2$ for all $p(X) \in V$.

## My attempt: Neither of the maps are linear.

I know that for a linear transformation it must be true that
$$T( p_1(x) + p_2(x))= T( p_1(x) )+ T(p_2(x)).$$

Here I take $p_1(X) =p_2(X)= X$, then for option $a)$,
$$T(p_1(X)+ p_2(X))\neq p_1(X^2) +p_2(X^2),$$
because
$$4X^2 \neq 2X^2.$$

Option b) same as like option $a)$.

Is my answer/logic correct or not correct ?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take another look at how the maps are defined, your example isn't a counter example for part (a), since in that case
$$T(X+X)=T(2X)=2(X^2)=2X^2,$$
and
$$T(X)+T(X)=X^2+X^2=2X^2.$$
You have however provided a counter example for (b).

Comment: thanks u @user505379......ya i missed that